# Why is my x0 set to 110.0, but the x coordinate in the resulting image still starts from 0?

Tags: python, mikeio

Why is my x0 set to 110.0, but the x coordinate in the resulting image still starts from 0?

```
print(x0, y0)
now = datetime.now()
forecast = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
datestr = forecast.strftime("%Y%m%d")
hour = now.hour
dfs_filename = f"dfs_{datestr}_{hour}.dfs2" 
coordinate = ['LONG/LAT', x0, y0, 0]    
items = [ItemInfo("Wind U", EUMType.Wind_Velocity, EUMUnit.meter_per_sec),
        ItemInfo("Wind V", EUMType.Wind_Velocity, EUMUnit.meter_per_sec)]  设置
dfs = Dfs2()
dfs.write(filename = dfs_filename,
           data = data, 
           start_time = start_time,
           dt = 3600, dx = dx, dy = dy,
           items = items,
           coordinate = coordinate)
```

> 110.0  20.65

Result

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

DFS2 is a raster file format, and a DFS2-file is always displayed with the coordinates of the raster cells measured from the bottom left, starting at 0,0 and then counting the rows and colums in the raster. The "world coordinates" of the cells are not displayed.